# C# - language-level design patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns

C# allows the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to be implemented via:

- The API: [IObservable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx), [IObserver<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx)
- The Language: [Events & Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(v=vs.71).aspx)

Are there any other examples of design patterns that C# implements at the language level?

Comment: `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`, events and delegates are not language features, they are classes in the .Net framework...

Comment: @ZoharPeled `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` are classes (The API). `event` and `delegate` are keywords (The Language) where `delegate` automatically implements `MulticastDelegate`, and `event` enforces a rule that events must be a delegate type. With respect, due to the fact that they're keywords in the language, they become language level constructs that implement the pattern.

Comment: Well, you have a point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `foreach` loop and `IEnumerable` - is Iterator Pattern from GoF
2. C# events are basically an implementation of 'Chain of Responsibility'
3. `Nullable<T>` types like `int?` - are an example of Decorator pattern.

Not exactly a language level but still:

4. `StringBuilder` class is an example of GoF Builder pattern.
5. WPF `ICommand` - Command pattern  from GoF

Comment: C# events are the Observer design pattern.